# MYSQL data + PHP to FLOTgraphing

Tags: php, mysql, flot

im quite new to mysql and flot graphing, but i get the general idea.
This is my scenario:
I receive data from a device, in which i put into mysql database.
am i wrong in saying that the new data will replace the existing data in the database?
i then need to plot that on a graph, how do i get(store) the old values so i can put in the data in this line?

```
 $(function () {
    var d4 = [[36,37],[50,51],null,[23,24],[18,17]];
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d4]);
  });
```

if not, i'll only be getting the current data... and that doesnt give me a line.. it'll give me datapoints haha
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you need to give us more to start off, you are asking some very general questions. How are you receiving data? How much MySQL do you know? There are some cases where you should get rid of old data and some where you should store. I think this question needs to be narrowed to one point.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
i'm receiving data from a device that calculates CO2, temperature. it then uses a c program in which will update the mysql database.
I guess i know basic mysql, create, insert, update, drop...
i guess my most direct question is you can create a table within a table in mysql, i want to extract the values (of the CO2 readings) and place them in the function above.

thanks for your help :)

Comment: i get it now, i was looking for "insert" instead of "update"

Comment: please write an answer to this question. State in your answer that you were supposed to use INSERT instead of update. Then accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to set the stage for a graph that you can recreate dynamically. To do so, grab your container then fire off an ajax call to the script that wraps up your data. Within the ajax success call, catch the script's results within a function and send it off to a method such as resetGraph that will reset the graph according to the new information found within the database.

```
var dataview = $("#placeholder");
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    data: "stuff&junk&things",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg){
        resetGraph(msg);
    }
});

function resetGraph( data ){

    plot = $.plot(dataview, data.data, {
        points: { show: true, radius: 5 },
        xaxis: { ticks: data.ticks, tickSize: 7 },
        yaxis: {labelHeight: 2}
    });

}
```

Your script should be populating arrays with the necessary information then json_encoding it before sending it back to Jquery. For example,

```
echo json_encode( 
    array( 
        "data" => array(
            array("data" => array(1,2,3))
        ),
        "ticks" => array(2, "two")
    )
);
```